# gzip.open as stdin for subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to kick off a program in python with `subprocess.Popen`, and `stdin` being some regular text file, like so.

```
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderrFile, stdin=open(TEXT_FILE))
```

and it works just fine. But if I try to open a gzipped file, my process fails.

```
import gzip
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderFile, stdin=gzip.open(GZFILE))
```

I'm not sure why. My process thinks it's not getting any data.

Any idea why? Shouldn't the 2 be interchangeable?

Comment: Is it Python 3? For me, `open` defaults to returning string data, while `gzip.open` is returning bytes.

Comment: no I'm using python2.7. you think that's the problem? My program does require string data as input. can i somehow "stringify" the `gzip.open` return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the return value of the `gzip.open(..)`, its internal file descriptor is passed to the file; reading it from the sub-process will return raw data, not the decompressed data.

You need to pass the decompressed data to subprocess' standard input:

```
subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=stdoutFile, stderr=stderFile,, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
with gzip.open(GZFILE) as f:
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, p.stdin)
# p.stdin.close()  # to denote the end of the file.
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @falsetru said, Popen uses the raw gzip data rather than the decompressed data. Here's a full example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import gzip
import subprocess
import shutil


filename = 'testfile'
data = 'Hello\n'

# Create some test files
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)

with gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(data)

# Make sure we can read them:
with open(filename) as f:
    d = f.read()
    print(d == data, d)

with gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'rt') as f:
    d = f.read()
    print(d == data, d)

# See what Popen does with the files given as stdin
with open(filename) as f:
    result = subprocess.Popen('hexdump -C'.split(), stdin=f,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout.read().decode())

with gzip.open(filename + '.gz') as f:
    result = subprocess.Popen('hexdump -C'.split(), stdin=f,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout.read().decode())


# Fix the problem like this...
p = subprocess.Popen('hexdump -C'.split(),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
with gzip.open(filename + '.gz', 'rb') as f:
    with p.stdin:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, p.stdin)
print(p.stdout.read().decode())

# You can use the same pattern for the regular files, too:
p = subprocess.Popen('hexdump -C'.split(),
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    with p.stdin:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f, p.stdin)
print(p.stdout.read().decode())
```

Output:

```
$ ./subprocess_gzip_stdin.py
True Hello

True Hello

00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006

00000000  1f 8b 08 08 fc 30 13 59  02 ff 74 65 73 74 66 69  |.....0.Y..testfi|
00000010  6c 65 00 f3 48 cd c9 c9  e7 02 00 16 35 96 31 06  |le..H.......5.1.|
00000020  00 00 00                                          |...|
00000023

00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006

00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a                                 |Hello.|
00000006
```